# android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction required

Tags: java, android

entering in code like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

comes up with this error "android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();" and has this as a quick fix which does in fact remove the error:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

and i am typing this in my main activity which extends  FragmentActivity . Does anybody know why? i have included:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

EDIT

```
 DescriptionFragment fragment = new DescriptionFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.pager, fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
```

changing getSupportFragmentManager() to getFragmentManager() requires me to change DescriptionFragment to android.app.Fragment...any ideas?

Comment: Add `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;` or `import android.support.v4.app.*;`

Comment: thanks...seems to be giving me this error: The import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction collides with another import statement

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With getSupportFragmentManager() you are getting the supportLibrary fragmentManager instead of the systems fragmentManager. So you are working with a transaction of the supportlibrary.

This is the reason why you need to add all these imports and use android.support.v4.app.

If you want to get the systems fragmentManager just try to use getFragmentManager() instead getSupportFragmentManager().

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your feedback..please check my updated question its still giving me issues

Comment: FragmentDescription is a class created by you? It's of type Fragment or SupportFragment?

Comment: FragmentDescription is created by me and extends Fragment

Comment: Well, I think that your main problem is that you are merging Fragments methods and SupportFragments methods. Wich objects you need? Basic fragments or SupportFragments? You need to use the support library? If you want to use the support library (to have compatibility with older systems), you cannot use any method of basic Fragments and have to use all methods of compatibility library. Fragments and supportFragment aren't compatible

Answer (score 3):

try this

public class DescriptionFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

instead of simply Fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Have you import android.support.v4.jar file to your project??

Comment: not sure what you mean by adding a .jar file? i've added it in my build path

Answer (score 2):

Ok...Just make a method for fragment and call this Like:

```
void addfragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addBacktoStack, int transition) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(transition);
    if (addBacktoStack)
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

}
```

**Now Just call Your Fragment:**

```
addfragment(new DescriptionFragment(this),true, FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
```

Comment: same thing seems to be happening.. this error appears for ft.replace: The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment). and this can be resolved by changing the start to this:   void addfragment(android.app.Fragment fragment, boolean addBacktoStack, int transition) {

Comment: You have to change android.support.v4.Fragment. I think this error occurs because of you have extends the fragment for android.app.Fragment so instead of you have to use android.support.v4.Fragment.. so you will get better solution.

Answer (score 1):

getActivity() slove my issue`android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 1):

In Activity import android.app.Fragment ..
In Fragment extend with android.app.Fragment..
this solved my issue...